# Estimating HMM parameters from a sequence with missing observations

Tags: estimation, missing-data, hidden-markov-model

The BW algorithm to estimate HMM parameters works on a consecutive sequence of observations. But what should be done if only a partial sequence is available? From another point of view, the observable may change its internal state without producing any output.

Can we say that a continuous-time HMM is less sensitive than a discrete-time one to this missing information when estimating the parameters?

P.S. I have faced the problem with a discrete-time HMM. I don't know whether we can estimate the parameters of a continuous-time one efficiently, or not.